# How to design a pulsed laser driver circuit?

Tags: circuit-design, laser, optoelectronics, laser-diode, laser-driver

I want to try a simple theoretical design of a pulsed aaser rriver circuit according to what specified in [this guideline](https://www.lasercomponents.com/de/?embedded=1&file=fileadmin/user_upload/home/Datasheets/lc/application-reports/lc-electronics/drive-electronics-pulsed-laser-diodes.pdf&no_cache=1) from LASER COMPONENTS. Since the guide is not exhaustive, I'd like to get some opinions about the design steps for the following circuit, proposed in the guide on page 3.

[image]

Here my questions.

**Question 1.** First of all, I don't really understand why a Common Emitter Voltage Amplifier configuration is proposed. The Laser Diode is a low input-impedance load, in sense that it needs a certain amount of forward bias current to properly work (even 30A peak current for a power laser).)  A transconductance amplifier, from outside behaving like a current source, wouldn't be more suitable? For instance by replacing R3 with the laser.

Suppose I've chosen a laser diode with my power, pulse length and frequency (of the desired pulse train) requirements. How should I choose the transistor? One may say it must have maximum collector current greater than that I want to flow in the laser according to my required output light power, but the collector current has nothing to do with the laser forward current because this is not a current source configuration. Again, this circuit is not clear for me.

**Question 2.**

The guideline on page 4 explains that the capacitor C2 is crucial as it will supply the laser while the input pulse train is off (0 Volt). It looks like the amplifier is utilized to charge C2 which actually provides current to the laser diode. Am I correct? Again, why not directly use the transistor to supply the laser? Anyway, the guide provides a really useful formula for designing C2:

C2 = Peak Current * Pulse Length / Vc

where Vc, by neglecting the inductances, will be determined by - good question.

**Question 3.** The guide says nothing about L1, L2, L3, L4. At the end of page 4, it explains how the laser and/or interconnections parasitic inductances will widen a narrow pulse (by increasing the rise and fall times). Won't, for instance, L2, deliberately inserted in the circuit, worsen that effect?

**Question 4.** What is the role of R4 and how to design it? It will just decrease the load (Laser + R4) input impedance by increasing the current provided by Vcc. I don't really understand its advantages. Maybe does it charges C2 when the input pulse is off, but the guide says C2 is charged through R3. should be R3 + R4.

Comment: I can't get the PDF to load, but the right half of the diagram is a model of a laser diode, so you don't deliberately put in those inductors or the resistors but rather try to pick a laser that minimizes those parasitics.

Comment: @user1850479 Thank you very much, that was a crucial answer I was looking for